# How to pass objects between threads when running a System.Diagnostics process

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, multithreading

I won't provide all code, but an example of what I want to do. I have this code for updating GUI elements from an external processes stderr.

I set up my process like this:

```
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo(command, arguments);

// Redirect the standard output of the process. 
info.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
info.RedirectStandardError = true;
info.CreateNoWindow = true;

// Set UseShellExecute to false for redirection
info.UseShellExecute = false;

proc = new Process();
proc.StartInfo = info;
proc.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

// Set our event handler to asynchronously read the sort output.
proc.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(proc_OutputDataReceived);
proc.ErrorDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(proc_ErrorDataReceived);
proc.Exited += new EventHandler(proc_Exited);

proc.Start();

// Start the asynchronous read of the sort output stream. Note this line!
proc.BeginOutputReadLine();
proc.BeginErrorReadLine();
```

I then have an event handler

```
void proc_ErrorDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Data != null)
    {
        UpdateTextBox(e.Data);
    }
}
```

Which invokes the following, which references a specific textbox control.

```
private void UpdateTextBox(string Text)
{
    if (this.InvokeRequired)
        this.Invoke(new Action<string>(this.SetTextBox), Text);
    else
    {
        textBox1.AppendText(Text);
        textBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
    }
}
```

What I want is something like this:

```
private void UpdateTextBox(string Text, TextBox Target)
{
    if (this.InvokeRequired)
        this.Invoke(new Action<string, TextBox>(this.SetTextBox), Text, Target);
    else
    {
        Target.AppendText(Text);
        Target.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
    }
}
```

That I can use to update different Textboxes with from that thread, without having to create a seperate function for every control in the GUI.

Is this possible? (obviously the code above does not work correctly)

Thanks.

**UPDATE**:

```
private void UpdateTextBox(string Text, TextBox Target)
{
    if (this.InvokeRequired)
        this.Invoke(new Action<string, TextBox>(this.**UpdateTextBox**), Text, Target);
    else
    {
        Target.AppendText(Text);
        Target.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
    }
}
```

This code does appear to work now as I noticed a typo.. is this ok to use?

Comment: Actually it looks like this does work, just that I have not changed SetTextBox to UpdateTextBox when I copied and pasted it.

Comment: Could you please explain the problem you are experiencing?

Comment: It works but if I put a break in there and look at "Target" in the IDE it says "'Target.Text' threw an exception of type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime.CrossThreadMessagingException'"

Answer (score 1):

The code you provided looks good and is good way to send such messages between threads.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this.

http://weblogs.asp.net/justin_rogers/pages/126345.aspx

I have done this before, but I don't have the code with me right now.

if I get to it I will post it for you, but the article might have enough information for you to figure out.